# DB Browser && Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I create Database in DB Browser For SQlite.
simple database - with one table called Students with two row:

1.id - integer
 2.name -text

I want to use this database in android studio app.For example I need an app,which will print the names of students from database Students;
I've two questions:

1. Where Should I put the Students.db file?
2. How to use/read the database in my app.

I'm searching for it for a while but cant find solution.
Can you give me a good tutorial or just answer the question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a well defined pattern of making a "DataBaseAdapter" class in Android.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite.html

Has an example.

you create a class `SQLiteHelper` that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Then you follow the general pattern that the SQLiteAdapter class follows. This approach handles creating the sqlite db for you within your app-private internal storage.

---

To read from the DB, you make an instance of your SQLiteAdapter class, and then call `insert(...)`, `delete(...)`, `query(...)`, etc. to actually manipulate your db.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would like to use an existing sqlite database, I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951805/how-to-access-an-existing-sqlite-database-in-android) rely on a same idea, that answer could help you too.
Or if you don't have to use an exiting database file, your starting point can be [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).